# Error for JButton ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm having a problem while adding an ActionListener for JButton, please help solving this issue.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at searchDB.searchDB(searchDB.java:11)
at Ramses.main(Ramses.java:35)
```

Main Class: Ramses.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import ...........;

public class Ramses {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Gui GuiObject = new Gui();
    GuiObject.Gui();

    searchDB searchObject = new searchDB();
    searchObject.searchDB(); //error here

}
}
```

Class where JButton is declared: Gui.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import........;

public class Gui {
public static JButton btnUpdate;
public void Gui() {
JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
    btnSearch.setBounds(463, 112, 91, 23);
    btnSearch.setVisible(true);
    pnUpper.add(btnSearch);

 }
}
```

Class where JButton ActionListener is implemented: searchDB.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class searchDB{

public void searchDB(){

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    Gui.btnSearch.addActionListener(handler); //error in this line

}
private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String cstmrSearch = (String) Gui.cbCustomer.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println("Selected Customer is :"+cstmrSearch);
    }


}
}
```

Any ideas what is the problem in this code??

Comment: thanks all for your answers, it is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would design my classes a bit different. I agree with @Reimeus, you should avoid mis-use of static fields, and you should avoid "pseudo"-constructors, constructors with void return types, since constructors should have no return type.

Specifically, I would change this:

```
public class Ramses {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gui GuiObject = new Gui();
    GuiObject.Gui();
    searchDB searchObject = new searchDB();
    searchObject.searchDB(); //error here
  }
}
```

to this:

```
public class Ramses {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gui gui = new Gui();  // variables should begin with lower-case letter
    // GuiObject.Gui();  // not needed
    SearchDB searchObject = new SearchDB(gui); // pass GUI object in
     // searchObject.searchDB(); // don't need this
  }
}
```

Change Gui from this:

```
public class Gui {
public static JButton btnUpdate;
public void Gui() {
JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
    btnSearch.setBounds(463, 112, 91, 23);
    btnSearch.setVisible(true);
    pnUpper.add(btnSearch);

 }
}
```

to this:

```
public class Gui {
  private JButton btnUpdate; // make private and non-static
  public Gui() {
    // JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
    //  btnSearch.setBounds(463, 112, 91, 23); // don't use absolute positioning
    //  btnSearch.setVisible(true);  // not needed

    btnUpdate = new btnUpdate("Search");
    pnUpper.add(btnSearch);
 }

 public AbstractButton getBtnUpdate() {
    return btnUpdate;
 }
}
```

and change searchDB from:

```
public class searchDB{

public void searchDB(){

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    Gui.btnSearch.addActionListener(handler); //error in this line

}
private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String cstmrSearch = (String) Gui.cbCustomer.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println("Selected Customer is :"+cstmrSearch);
    }


}
}
```

to:

```
public class SearchDB{  // class names begin with upper-case

  public SearchDB(Gui gui){  // no more pseudo-constructors! And pass in Gui object
    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    gui.getBtnUpdate().addActionListener(handler); // call method
  }

  private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // String cstmrSearch = (String) Gui.cbCustomer.getSelectedItem();
        String cstmrSearch = gui.getSelectedCustomer(); // give Gui this method
        System.out.println("Selected Customer is :"+cstmrSearch);
    }

  }
}
```

(see comments in code for explanation)

Answer (score 2):

The stacktrace is a good indicator of the problem

Remove the `void` keyword from the constructor of `Gui`

```
public Gui() {
```

to allow the component variable to be assigned. In addition remove the `JButton`type in the constructor to ensure that the variable is not being [shadowed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1):

```
btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
```

Aside: `static` fields are considered poor design, use instance variables instead

Answer (score 0):

If you were intending to add constructor to `Class Gui` and `Class searchDB`, you should not add void as return type.

Adding void would make it a normal method. A constructor will have no return type. Also you can have the initialization code inside the constructor and this initialization will be made when you create the object of the class. No need make any explicit invocation.

```
Class Gui {

public Gui(){
 //initialization code goes here
}

}

Class searchDB{

public searchDB(){
 //initialization code goes here
}
}
```